# How do you make network applications available to all your users under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

We have 3000 users and have many programs that run from the network (i.e. no local files, exe runs from mapped drive), under Windows 7 we redirect the start menu to a UNC path containing the short cuts to these programs (approx 50). This is very messy as the all end up mixed in with the programs installed locally (Start\Programs). Can anyone offer any suggestions on how we could make these short cuts easily accessible? Our users struggle to find program X after scrolling up and down for 5 minutes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create folder(s) with shortcuts and pin link(s) to this folder(s) to start menu... 
It's not so difficult and can be done remotely with scripting (logon script or so on).

BTW: To enable 'Pin to Start menu' menu item create subkey named **{a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8}** in **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers** and this option will be available in folder context menu appeared on *Shift+Right click*.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Many thanks for that, I have added a folder to the start menu which looks great. I'm unable to find and example vbscript that would do the same, have you done this yourself?

Comment: Sorry, seems I was too optimistic about it - it's easy to pin shortcut to executable file to start menu but it not so easy for folder... You can try it to the following way: 1) implement registry settings described above to your clients using Group Policy (or with any other available method) 2) run script to start explorer.exe with your target folder selected and send keystrokes to it to open context menu, select "Pin to start menu" menu item and close this explorer window.

Comment: Here is the code of script:
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "explorer.exe /e,/select,""\\server\share\"""
wscript.sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "+{F10}"
WshShell.SendKeys "@u"
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"

Comment: 'sleep' command is necessary to wait while process started, '+{F10}' = Shift+F10 = 'keyboard shortcut' for right mouse click and '%{F4}'=Alt-F4 to close program.

Unfortunately I cant test it with network folder right now, but this script works well for local folders. I hope you succeed